# How to open non-google navigation from my app?

Tags: android, android-intent, navigation

I am using code below to start google navigation. Is there any way to open non-google navigation from application?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Berlin+Germany")); 
        startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific URI format defined for non-Google navigation apps. You can add support for specific apps by checking if they have a URI you can implement, but there's no way to create a single 'open navigation app' intent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But is there any way to extend list of suggested navigation aps? For now I have only web browser and google maps. I would like to choose NaviExpert but there is no way for now.

Comment: I'm not Polish so my research is sort of limited, but unfortunately I'm not seeing a way to launch NaviExpert via an intent. Unless it supports Google Maps URIs (in which case it would already work), I don't think you can do that, sorry.